# How to get webform submissions from Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-webform

I have installed modules `Services`, `Services Entity`, `Services Entity Reference`, `REST Server`. My endpoint is `api`, and I have `webform` called `Feedback`. I can retrieve `webform` calling URL `http://mysite/api/entity_node/999.json`. But I have no idea how to get submissions from API `http://mysite/node/999/webform-results`. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this link https://drupal.org/project/webform_service.

Then it is possible to get results by -

```
/api/webform/[webform_uuid]/submissions
```